# Using nonce when loading posts with AJAX

Tags: ajax, security, nonce

This is more of a security question. I have a blog layout that has a loader at the bottom of my posts, and when you get to it, ajax call will be triggered, it will call the function that will render more posts.

This all works. But one thing is bothering me: should I use `POST` or `GET` method? the `GET` won't trigger nonce issues when doing code sniffing using `phpcs`, while with `POST` I get the

> Processing form data without nonce verification

error.

Now, all I am doing is fetching posts from the database by calling the callback function that is hooked to `wp_ajax` and `wp_ajax_nopriv` actions.

Should I be worried about security in this case, and append a nonce field in my blog, or should I just use `GET` method instead?

Comment: I don't understand: Nonces are for users who are logged in only. Why do you want to use one for anonymous users? They'd get all the same nonce.

Comment: The thing is, normally I wouldn't when just loading posts (I'm not submitting any form to the server, only fetching posts). But Was just wondering should I use `GET` or `POST` when loading, and how to solve the issue that code sniffer requires nonce validation any time I use `POST`?

Comment: That is, is there a proffered method, when using ajax to fetch posts?

Comment: If you just want to **get** more posts, use GET. Use POST if you want to store data. And then you need additional security measures.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew what exactly should I use, since I can get posts using both methods successfully. I mean it makes sense to use `GET`, but I read that `GET` isn't secure as `POST` is, so that got me worried a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` puts all your params on the URL like;

```
http://example.com/thing?foo=bar&x=y
```

For `POST` you could include all that information but it won't show in the URL.

```
http://example.com/thing
```

Obviously if you're thinking about security, using `POST` is more ideal because your params won't show in access logs or accidentally picked up by search engines or whatever. Sending passwords using this method is ideal in additional to large amounts of data.

But what you can loose with `POST` is caching. Some systems will not cache a `POST`. Assuming you want to ditch the the cache on a `GET` request you can always throw on a cache buster.

```
http://example.com/thing?foo=bar&x=y&cache=234234234
```

Where `&cache=<current-time-or-random-number>`. And maybe that's what you want for your more posts. To not cache them so you're always getting the freshest of the fresh. Unfortunately if you do anything at scale this idea fails. Cache is King and controlling the cache is ideal.

Enter the `TTL` (Time to Live) where you can add how long you'd like your resource to be cached on the other end.

```
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + (60 * 60))); // 1 hour
```

or [`nocache_headers()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/nocache_headers) `// no caching`

Now, for your case, I don't think it matters one bit which one you use. But the questions to ask yourself should include;

- Do you want to expose your data passed to the URL?
- Should you be concerned with caching?
- How can you control caching to make it optimized for your content and system?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation on the pros and cons. I'll see about caching.